# ld.exe||cannot open output file bin\Debug\<FILENAME>.exe Permission denied [C++]

Tags: c++

I've already googled this and found that checking if the .exe is already open in task manager may help, it did not. (In this case my file is called TextFighter.exe). PROOF:
[image: enter code here]`

Comment: Do you have permission to write into that folder ?
Else try logging off and re-linking

Answer (score 2):

because the FILENAME.exe's process is still running, you can just kill all the process of this program. you can open an cmd and run this Command：

```
taskkill -IM <FILENAME>.exe /F
```

In your case you can try :

```
taskkill -IM TextFighter.exe /F
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if the program is still open or running in the debugger. Ensure you close out any old debugging sessions.